# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED for Node.js and socket.io application?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ECONNREFUSED on Port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792869/econnrefused-on-port-80)

Up until today, my app was working, but then all of a sudden it stopped: it started throwing these errors every time I try to connect to the socket.io-enabled part of the app.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
     at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:661:19)
```

Here are my module version numbers.

```
CompassionPit@0.5.2 /opt/chat
├── async@0.1.18
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├─┬ connect@2.0.2
│ ├── debug@0.7.0
│ ├── formidable@1.0.9
│ ├── mime@1.2.4
│ └── qs@0.4.2
├── date-utils@1.2.9
├─┬ ecstatic@0.1.6
│ ├── ent@0.0.4
│ └── mime@1.2.5
├─┬ express@2.5.8
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.7
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.5
│ │ └── qs@0.5.0
│ ├── mime@1.2.4
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ └── qs@0.4.2
├─┬ flatiron@0.1.17
│ ├─┬ broadway@0.1.15
│ │ ├─┬ cliff@0.1.7
│ │ │ └── eyes@0.1.7
│ │ ├── eventemitter2@0.4.9
│ │ ├─┬ nconf@0.5.1
│ │ │ ├── async@0.1.22
│ │ │ ├── ini@1.0.2
│ │ │ └─┬ optimist@0.3.4
│ │ │   └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.3.1
│ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ utile@0.0.10
│ │ │ ├── async@0.1.22
│ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
│ │ │ ├── ncp@0.2.6
│ │ │ └── rimraf@1.0.9
│ │ └─┬ winston@0.5.11
│ │   ├── async@0.1.22
│ │   ├── eyes@0.1.7
│ │   ├─┬ loggly@0.3.11
│ │   │ ├── request@2.9.202
│ │   │ └── timespan@2.2.0
│ │   └── stack-trace@0.0.6
│ ├── director@1.0.10
│ ├─┬ optimist@0.3.4
│ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ ├── pkginfo@0.2.3
│ └─┬ prompt@0.1.12
│   ├── async@0.1.22
│   └─┬ winston@0.5.11
│     ├── async@0.1.22
│     ├── eyes@0.1.7
│     ├─┬ loggly@0.3.11
│     │ ├── request@2.9.202
│     │ └── timespan@2.2.0
│     └── stack-trace@0.0.6
├── geoip@0.4.5
├── hashlib2@1.0.3
├── http-digest@v0.1.0
├─┬ jade@0.20.3
│ ├── commander@0.5.2
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.3
├── marked@0.2.1
├─┬ mongoose@2.5.10
│ ├── hooks@0.2.0
│ └── mongodb@0.9.9-4
├─┬ mysql@0.9.5
│ └─┬ hashish@0.0.4
│   └── traverse@0.6.1
├── nave@0.2.13  extraneous
├─┬ optimist@0.2.8
│ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
├── request@2.1.1
├─┬ socket.io@0.9.0
│ ├── policyfile@0.0.4
│ ├── redis@0.6.7
│ └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.0
│   ├─┬ ws@0.4.0
│   │ ├── commander@0.5.0
│   │ └── options@0.0.3
│   └── xmlhttprequest@1.2.2
├── sqwish@0.2.0
├── uglify-js@1.2.5
├── underscore@1.3.1
├─┬ union@0.1.8
│ ├── pkginfo@0.2.3
│ └── qs@0.3.2
└─┬ vows@0.5.13
  └── eyes@0.1.7
```

Comment: did you upgrade your node.js in system ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using node 0.6.19 and it didn't fix the problems.

Comment: Is the server you try to connect to running? `ECONNREFUSED` is the typical error you get when the server you try to connect to is not running, i.e. there is no-one listening on the other side.

Comment: Paul Hazen, it's not an exactly duplicate.  The problem was I was using an outdated version of @felixge 's node-mysql module.  Simply that.   I also set socket.io to bind to my server's specific IP address.

Comment: Are you implying your problem is resolved? "The problem was..." seems to indicate you solved your problem. If you solved it, could you post your answer and mark it correct for other people who run into the same problem in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowing NodeJS to run on port 80? If not you might want to take a look at this: [Node.js: ECONNREFUSED on Port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792869/econnrefused-on-port-80)

Comment: https://github.com/zackster/CompassionPit--Node- See app.js, at the bottom.